# Is the phrase "benefit from experiences" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> We can **benefit from experiences** of other developers.
>
> We can **benefit from experiences** of development.

Is the selected phrase idiomatic?

Comment: I really don't think so. Just a normal phrase.

Comment: Isn't it the meaning of idiomatic?

Comment: How would it be? 'Benefit' is a very abstract term, any advantages you gain, physical or just knowledge, benefit you. You *benefit from [a source]*, that's the preposition you use for this meaning. Experiences of others or your own may be such a source. Nothing idiomatic about that.

Comment: What do you think idiomatic means? According to its definition it means "using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker." So what you are explaining about the phrase is that the phrase is idiomatic.

Comment: seems like this definition is incomplete in that it doesn't include the part the expressions are completely unnatural to language learners and don't follow the usual rules of the language, utilizing either unusual grammar constructs or words in obscure metaphorical meaning.

Comment: While *idiomatic* can mean something peculiar to only a small group of people, that's not how it's normally used—unless you specifically qualify it with such a statement. In general, *idiomatic* just means something that's used and understood. So, you're quite right that it's strange to think that a normal phrase would *not* be considered idiomatic in general. In that more normal sense, your sentences *are* idiomatic. The only thing I suggest is adding *the* before *experiences* and using the singular *experience* before *development*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: So about every single common word and grammar construct is idiomatic? Saying "This is a book" when one points at a book, one utters an idiom?

Comment: @SF It depends on context. It's certainly not an *idiom*, but it's idiomatic in the sense that it's language that people use. If you say that something is *unidiomatic* you mean that it's *not* used or understood by (most) people. Of course, you're free to interpret the word in the strict sense that you have, applying it to every context.

Comment: @SF. To echo what Jason has said, "This is a book" is not an *idiom*, but it is definitely *idiomatic*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of knowledge and skills, we typically use "experience" as an uncountable noun. The best way to write your first sentence would be:

> We can benefit from **the experience** of other developers.

When used as a countable noun, each experience refers to a specific occasion. One might say "I have had many good experiences with that business" to mean that their individual interactions with the business have been pleasant. Your second sentence *could* be understood with this second meaning, such that "experiences of development" means "occasions when you have experienced the development process". However, this is unusual, and the more idiomatic sentence would still use the uncountable form, as in:

> We can benefit from **the experience** of development.

Comment: As you say, experience can be either countable or uncountable, depending on how it's interpreted. I personally think the first sentence sounds better with the individual (learning) *experiences* of other developers (as related to us). ("Talk to the other people hear. Learn from them.") But I'm just viewing it differently—and putting the sentence in the context of an employee at a company, not developers in general.

Comment: @JasonBassford Your interpretation isn't wrong, but it seems less natural to me. The source of the benefit is the fact that the other developers are *experienced*, which is to say they *have experience*, rather than the fact that they happen to have gone through some experiences. When you specify "learning experiences", it makes more sense, but otherwise I would expect "experience of developers" to refer to knowledge and skills. An interviewer would ask "what development experience do you have" rather than "what development experiences have you had", no?